# Getting destination of scheduled WEBI report using Rest API?

Tags: business-objects, rest, webi

The thing I want to accomplish is to run a report instance from the SAP BO portal with the same parameters (Document type, destination, etc) as given during scheduling the report. This can be done on the BI portal in the following way:
*(Right Click on the) Report -> (Select) History -> (Right Click on any pending) schedule -> Select Run Now*

(A new instance is created and the destination and format remains the same)
The solution I was trying, is to get details of a schedule nd use the same parameters and run the report now.

I tried using this URIs:

1. Get http:///v1///schedules/<schedule_id> (Gives details of the schedule)
2. Get http:///v1///instances/<instance_id> (Gives details of the instances of the schedule)

Both the responses don't have the destination details.
My question is how do I get the  destination details?
Or is there any other way to accomplish running an instance of a schedule now?

PS: The report has already been scheduled in the portal, I just want to run an instance of the report through the Rest API and keep the parameters(including the destination paramter) same as that for the schedule.

Any help would be really appreciated ☺️

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please include your code to show what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, as mentioned I have used two URIs in the get request both of them return a response which contains the type of the output, scheduled time and other parameters but does not contain the destination details.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: if you don't see the destination details in the response, the scheduled report is using the default destination. Excerpt from [API docu](https://help.sap.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/35c6f32a19f24f07ac9260766e33b94d.html):

**(GET .../documents//schedules/)**

> Is optional. If no destination is specified, then the default destination is the one defined by the administrator on the BI platform via the CMC ( Servers  Web Intelligence Services  Adaptive Job Server  Destination )

I don't know whether it is possible to retrieve the server default destination, but I assume not.

Comment: I have tried scheduling a report and keeping the destination as email to my inbox. But it did not reflect in the get request call that I had made to check the schedule details of this same report. So even if it wasn't default location, it didn't show up in the response. I expected that I would see my email id and that the destination is email in the response body but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The link you have shared is for getting the parameters to be filled and creating a new schedule.

Comment: `The link you have shared is for getting the parameters to be filled and creating a new schedule` nope, the link is about [getting schedule details](https://help.sap.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/45f8f8836e041014910aba7db0e91070.html), I got the response body description from there

Comment: But the reponse does not include the destination details (for example who will be receiving through email or if it's FTP- those details).